# Trouble with setting the vertical position of text

Tags: html, css

[image]

I've been trying to replicate this picture, which is a navigation bar on a Chinese forum. The picture is in Chinese but I believe you should be able to get the point. In short, the text is not vertically centered but 2px closer to the upper border. I tried setting line-height for it but doing so makes the text vertically centered instead. Does anyone know how to adjust the text to "move it up" a little bit? Thank you.

The following is the code I write:

```css
#box {
  width: 280px;
  background-color: #333;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #fff;
}

.content {
  /*height: 30px;*/
  border-top: 1px dotted #fff;
  text-align: left;
  font: 14px/30px "宋体";
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>练习1</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="box">
    <div class="content" id="syllabus">课程大纲</div>
 <div class="content" id="video">妙味视频</div>
 <div class="content" id="forum">妙味论坛</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `position: relative; top: -2px;` OR `transform: translateY(-2px);` ?

Comment: No isolated problem code no help.

Comment: Show us the HTML and CSS corresponding to what you're trying to center please

Comment: @Gropai if you accepted the answer, an upvote is the way to go :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added `position:relative;` and `top:-2px;` to your `.content` css:

```css
#box {
  width: 280px;
  background-color: #333;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #fff;
}

.content {
  /*height: 30px;*/
  border-top: 1px dotted #fff;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 14px/30px "宋体";
  color: #fff;
  position:relative;
  top: -2px;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>练习1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="box">
        <div class="content" id="syllabus">课程大纲</div>
        <div class="content" id="video">妙味视频</div>
        <div class="content" id="forum">妙味论坛</div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the CSS3 Flexbox module. Just working on the `.content` selector would do the trick.

```css
#box {
  width: 280px;
  background-color: #333;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #fff;
}

.content {
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  /* center vertically if flex-direction is row */
  /* center horizontally if flex-direction is column */
  align-items: center;
  /* center horizontally if flex-direction is row */
  /* center vertically if flex-direction is column */
  /* justify-content: center; */
  border-top: 1px dotted #fff;
  text-align: left;
  font: 14px/30px "宋体";
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div class="content" id="syllabus">课程大纲</div>
  <div class="content" id="video">妙味视频</div>
  <div class="content" id="forum">妙味论坛</div>
</div>
```